# Residue from managed package problem

Tags: managed-package, custom-field, platform-bug

I installed and then uninstalled a managed package on a sandbox multiple times. Then when I last tried to install the package again it gave some wierd errors(5 of them):

1. (Activity.Custom_Field__c) No clean data columns available for custom fields.
   No clean data columns available for custom fields.

Then I found out this: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000126971&language=en_U

It says to create the fields in the error message and then delete them again. I thought that makes sense and I created most of them but on the last two it hit me with another error when I clicked save:

*Unable to Access Page
The value of a parameter contains a character that is not allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length. Remove the character from the parameter value or reduce the value length and resubmit. If the error still persists, report it to our Customer Support team. Provide the URL of the page you were requesting as well as any other related information.*

Also the last part from the URL is like this:  **common.config.field.CustomFieldNoCleanColumn**

Any help? Could I do something to get rid of that error from workbench?

Comment: Any option other than raising case to salesforce support please?

Comment: Sorry @PratapJadhavar, couldn't find another way. Why not asking SF for support? This seems like a platform bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens in our test org every couple of months due to repeated re-installs.

Each time, we open a case with Salesforce and request that they perform a physical delete on the fields, which they do.

We also empty the Recycle Bin before opening the case as this needs to be done before they can perform the physical delete.

Comment: Yeah, the support guys from SF were very helpful!